# Sorting chosen strings in column of matrix

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

We want to sort "names" alphebeticaly while sill making sure the appropriate grade (grraides) are given to the right student.

```
print("List of grades are:")
grraids=computeFinalGrade(pure_data)
kn=np.column_stack((names,grraids))
for names in sorted(kn):
    print(kn)
```

[image]

We get that out, but would very much like those names to be in alphebetical order, but keeping the function general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, didn't realize it was a numpy array, code has been changed accordingly. However, it still assumes the student name is always in the same place. (first spot)

```
import numpy as np
grades = np.array([["B",10],["C",8],["A",3]])
print grades
grades.sort(axis=0)
print grades
```

Output:

```
[['B' '10']
 ['C' '8']
 ['A' '3']]
[['A' '10']
 ['B' '3']
 ['C' '8']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Didn't realize it was a numpy array. At least, im assuming np refers to numpy

Comment: I get the return input TypeError: unorderable types: float() > str(). When i write grades.sort(axis=1), i sort the values after the smallest to largest grade, but when i write grades.sort(axis=0) it returns the type error. Any sugestions?

Comment: It seems like you have mixed numbers and strings in the first position of the pairs of (students,results). I.e. Theres a pair somewhere which is something like`[2.0,"b"]`. I would try `print kn` to have a look at the data first to make sure the first column is only names

Comment: We, accidentaly put a space in before M. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help!